DEP6957 while deploying Application to HoloLens 2
i want to deploy an application to my HoloLens 2. It worked fine until yesterday when my computer crashed.
Now i build my application in unity with the following settings:

I open the .sln file with visual studio.
I have tried two approaches - usb-connection and deployment over wifi:
Wifi:

my computer and the HoloLens are in the same network.

Developer Settings on HoloLens are activated

"Remote Machine" is selected

My Configuration Properties for debugging look like this:


the ip adress is the one my HoloLens shows me, if i ask it.

I retrieve the following error:
Error DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '169.254.000.00' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - A connection attempt failed because the remote station did not respond correctly after a certain period of time, or the established connection was faulty because the connected host did not respond. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274C) [0x8007274C]
Build 1 Succeeded - Deploy 1 failed.


USB-Connection:

Device is selected
I did not specify any settings (Maybe wrong?)
Start the Application and retrieve the following message:
Error DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - No connection could be established because the target computer refused the connection. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274D) [0x8007274D]
Build 1 Succeeded - Deploy 1 failed.

Maybe its a useful information that i am able to connect to the windows device portal.
Hope someone has got an idea, i tried multiple approaches e.g.
Deploying with Visual Studio 2019 to Hololens 2 and
Deployment from unity to Hololens 2 giving error DEP6957

Based on the error messages, this was likely caused by unpairing. Could you check if your PC is paired with the HoloLens device?
Additionally, please try using Visual Studio 2022 instead of 2019 version, which can also cause issues while deploying. See recommended VS version and the necessary workloads on it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/install-the-tools#installation-checklist.
